# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Footscray'

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to transform and then fit data frame into linear regression, however considering this value error I have checked all columns but no columns that has this value.

Transformation:

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

pipeline = make_column_transformer((StandardScaler(), ['Price']),
                                  (OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['Type', 'Method', 'Regionname','CouncilArea']))
pipeline.fit_transform(df)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import sklearn.metrics


def cross_val(model):
    g = cross_val_score(X, y, model, cv=5)
    return g.mean()

def evaluate_print(true,predicted):
    mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(true,predicted)
    rmse = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(true,predicted))
    mae = metrics.mean_absolute_error(true,predicted)
    print('MSE -- > ', mse)
    print('RMSE -- > ', mse)
    print('MAE -- > ', mae)
    return mse, rmse, mae
    
def evaluate(true,predicted):
    mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(true,predicted)
    rmse = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(true,predicted))
    mae = metrics.mean_absolute_error(true,predicte)
    return mse, rmse, mae

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)

evaluate_print(y_test, y_pred)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_34/2472020570.py in <module>
      4 
      5 linreg = LinearRegression()
----> 6 linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Footscray'
```

Comment: You need to check why you have the word "Footscray" in your `X_train` or `y_train`. That's your issue. In which feature you can find this word? Probably you have a problem with the `OneHotEncoder`.